# Pandas loc does not work to subset DataFrame when using a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am fairly new to Python, especially pandas. I have a DataFrame called KeyRow which is from a bigger df:

```
KeyRow=df.loc[df['Order'] == UniqueOrderName[i]]
```

Then I make a nested loop

```
for i in range (0,len(PersonNum)):
   print(KeyRow.loc[KeyRow['Aisle'] == '6', 'FixedPill'])
```

So it appears to only work when a constant is placed, whereas if I use PersonNum[0] instead of '6',even though both values are equivalent, it appears not to work. When I use PersonNum[i] this is the output I am getting:

```
Series([], Name: FixedPill, dtype: object)
```

Whereas if I use 'x' I get a desired result:

```
15    5
Name: FixedPill, dtype: object
```

Comment: For starters, `range (0,len(PersonNum))` is returning `int` while `'6'` is a string so you'll probably be seeing `TypeError: invalid type comparison`.

Comment: That fixed things. I made PersonNum into a string. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little unclear what your are trying to accomplish with this questions. If you are looking to filter a DataFrame, then I would suggest to never do this in an iterative manner. You should take full advantage of the slicing capabilities of `.loc`. Consider the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6],
                   [1,2,3], [2,5,6],
                   [1,2,3], [4,5,6],
                   [1,2,3], [4,5,6]], 
                  columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df.head()

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   1   2   3
3   2   5   6
4   1   2   3
```

Suppose you have a list of PersonNum that you want to use to locate the a particular field where your list is `PersonNum = [1, 2]`. You can slice the DataFrame in one step by performing:

```
df.loc[df["A"].isin(PersonNum), "B"]
```

Which will return a pandas Series and

```
df.loc[df["A"].isin(PersonNum), "B"].to_frame()
```

which returns a new DataFrame. Utilizing the `.loc` is ***significantly faster*** than an iterative approach.